# Only return value that matches the ID on table 1

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-xi

I have tried all possible joins and sub-queries but I cant get the data to only return one value from table 2 that exactly matches the vendor ID. If I dont have the address included in the query, I get one hit for the vendor ID. How can I make it so that when I add the address, I only want the one vendor that I get prior to adding the address.

The vendor from table one must be VEN-CLASS IS NOT NULL.

[image: Image from the query]

This was my last attempt using subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR_VNAME,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR_CONTCT,
            APVENMAST.TAX_ID,
            Subquery.ADDR1
 FROM (TEST.dbo.APVENMAST APVENMAST
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT APVENADDR.ADDR1,
            APVENADDR.VENDOR_GROUP,
            APVENADDR.VENDOR,
            APVENMAST.VEN_CLASS
       FROM TEST.dbo.APVENADDR APVENADDR
            INNER JOIN TEST.dbo.APVENMAST APVENMAST
               ON     (APVENADDR.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP)
                  AND (APVENADDR.VENDOR = APVENMAST.VENDOR)
      WHERE (APVENMAST.VEN_CLASS IS NOT NULL)) Subquery
       ON     (APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP = Subquery.VENDOR_GROUP)
          AND (APVENMAST.VENDOR = Subquery.VENDOR))
   INNER JOIN TEST.dbo.APVENLOC APVENLOC
      ON     (APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENLOC.VENDOR_GROUP)
         AND (APVENMAST.VENDOR = APVENLOC.VENDOR)
 WHERE (APVENMAST.VEN_CLASS IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: It looks like all of the returned values in your screenshot are distinct, relative to the selected columns (i.e the vendor id appears to be associated to multiple addresses.)  How do you know which address is the one you want?  Does it matter which of the vendor addresses returned is used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP
, APVENMAST.VENDOR
, APVENMAST.VENDOR_VNAME
, APVENMAST.VENDOR_CONTCT
, APVENMAST.TAX_ID
, APVENADDR.ADDR1
FROM TEST.dbo.APVENMAST APVENMAST
INNER JOIN (
    select VENDOR_GROUP, VENDOR, ADDR1
    , row_number() over (partition by VENDOR_GROUP, VENDOR order by ADDR1) r
    from TEST.dbo.APVENADDR
) APVENADDR
ON  APVENADDR.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP
AND APVENADDR.VENDOR = APVENMAST.VENDOR
AND APVENADDR.r = 1
--do you need this table; you're not using it...
--INNER JOIN TEST.dbo.APVENLOC APVENLOC
--ON  APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENLOC.VENDOR_GROUP
--AND APVENMAST.VENDOR = APVENLOC.VENDOR
WHERE APVENMAST.VEN_CLASS IS NOT NULL
--if the above inner join was to filter results, you can do this instead:
and exists (
    select top 1 1 
    from TEST.dbo.APVENLOC APVENLOC
    ON  APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENLOC.VENDOR_GROUP
    AND APVENMAST.VENDOR = APVENLOC.VENDOR
)
```

Comment: Thank you @JohnBevan! For some reason, the query takes for ever to run. I, however, found another column in the APVENLOC table that I can filter on to get the unique vendor. Turns out if the vendor address is for the main office, the vendor location is set blank.

Answer (score 0):

I found another column in the APVENLOC table that I can filter on to get the unique vendor. Turns out if the vendor address is for the main office, the vendor location is set blank.

Easier than I thought it would be!

```
SELECT DISTINCT APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR_VNAME,
            APVENADDR.ADDR1,
            APVENMAST.VENDOR_SNAME,
            APVENADDR.LOCATION_CODE,
            APVENMAST.VEN_CLASS
FROM TEST.dbo.APVENMAST APVENMAST
   INNER JOIN TEST.dbo.APVENADDR APVENADDR
      ON     (APVENMAST.VENDOR_GROUP = APVENADDR.VENDOR_GROUP)
         AND (APVENMAST.VENDOR = APVENADDR.VENDOR)
WHERE (APVENADDR.LOCATION_CODE = '    ')
```

Shaji